# How to disable portrait orientation on UINavigationController rootViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

I have a class, HomeView, as the rootViewController of a UINavigationController on my iPad application. Only landscape orientation is set in the info.plist file and HomeView does not implement `shouldRotateToInterfaceOrientation:`, however the view is rotating for both orientations while the simulator is rotating.

How do I only use the landscape orientations in my UIViewController?

Comment: It is worth noting that there are four orientations. Portrait, PortraitUpsideDown, LandscapeLeft & LandscapeRight. Which are you setting in your plist.info file?

Answer (score 5):

If you do not implement **shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:** the runtime will call the method on the Super class, **UIViewController**.

Instead you should respond appropriately to the method with the orientations you want to rotate to:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    BOOL shouldAutorotate = NO;

    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
        || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

        shouldAutorotate = YES;
    }

    return shouldAutorotate;
}
```

Take a look at the [UIInterfaceOrientation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIInterfaceOrientation) reference page and the [UIViewController's shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:) reference page for more information.

Comment: Shorter version: `return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);`

Comment: True, but the shorter version may not explain why it is the answer. Only teach them to copypasta.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't remove the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method; that will not stop the interface from rotating, it will only not execute any code that you could have in that method. You should instead try something like this (assuming that you don't ever want the interface to rotate):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to avoid completely preventing rotation - instead, consider `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` to return `YES` for `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` or `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`. (Also, `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is deprecated as of iOS 6 - you'll also want `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations`)