# How can I Launch my application in Landscape?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I want to start my application in Landscape orientation, after app starts that I want to give support for all orientation. I have set "Initial interface orientation property" to "Landscape (left home button)" in info.plist.

Even if I put iPad in Landscape, my app starts in Portrait mode. How can I solve this issue?

Thank you,

Akshay

Answer (score 1):

By Default the orientation setting in plist would look like this in Xcode 4.x
[image]

Change the order as shown below (Or according to your need, the item 0 will the orientation in which the app launches by default)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could implement [- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:) on your **UIViewController** and return true when the device is in a landscape position.

Then once you want to support all orientations, let: [- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:) respond appropriately by setting a boolean flag after [- (void)viewDidAppear:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidAppear:) in your **UIViewController**.

For further reading on how to implement shouldAuto... see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8349691/768510) to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the UIInterfaceOrientation in your app's Info.plist file to set the "Initial interface orientation" (key displayed when your editing the plist without displaying raw value/keys.

Look at : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

which specifies :
UIInterfaceOrientation | “Initial interface orientation” | Specifies the initial orientation of the application’s user interface. See “UIInterfaceOrientation” for details.

Then if you haven't set the UILaunchImageFile property, it will display the default launch image :
"You would include the UILaunchImageFile~ipad key in your Info.plist file and set its value to MyiPadImage.png. You would then include a MyiPadImage-Portrait.png file and a MyiPadImage-Landscape.png file in your bundle to specify the corresponding launch images."

Answer (score 0):

If you always want your app to start in Landscape, you should remove any Portrait orientations from the "Supported interface orientations" (in the plist, or in the project settings > Summary (in Xcode 4) or project settings > General (in Xcode 5).

If you want Portrait to be available later (after launch):

In iOS 5 (and lower):
Implement `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in your root view controller to return `YES` for any orientations you want to allow (in this case, `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait`, `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft`, and `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`. This will override any interface orientations that you've disallowed in "Supported interface orientations"

In iOS 6 (and higher):
In your app delegate, implement `- (NSUInteger)application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` and return a `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` for the orientations we want to allow post-launch (in this case, `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown`). Then, in the root view controller, implement `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations`, returning whatever orientations should be available in the current state of the app.

If you need some example code or more details, you can check out [my blog post](http://labs.adamluptak.com/device-orientation-in-ios/) on the subject.