# Auto Detect Device Orientation

Tags: ios

How to achieve the following functionalities in iphone app.

Always app launch portrait mode. if the simulator is landscape mode first launch in portrait mode then detect the device orientation change the app according to the current device orientation.

Comment: Possible Duplicate : **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604237/how-can-i-launch-my-application-in-landscape?rq=1**

Answer (score 0):

Either you can disable all orientations except portrait in your project and then set orientation programmatically throughout your app. Or you can stop orientation for specific view controller (may be in your case, viewcontroller during launching) by returning value NO. like this

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return NO;
}
```

and as mentioned by @Conner

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
```

}